# Cannot compile support-v4 lib with Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I migrate my android app from eclipse to Android Studio. During this "migration" I decided to split my project in 4 modules: GUI module, engine module, commons module and resources module.

`The problem is that I cannot include v4 or v7 libs... It does not recognize the import:"import android.support.v4."`

Below are the gradles:

1.Genral Gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

1.Gradle for GUI module(main module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile project(':audiorecengine')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.audioRec"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 73
        versionName "4.0.4"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        lite {
            applicationId = "com.audioRec"
            versionCode 73
            versionName "4.0.4"
        }
        pro {
            applicationId = "com.audioRec.pro"
            versionCode 13
            versionName "3.0.3"
        }
    }
}
```

2. Gradle for engine module:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

   android {
   compileSdkVersion 22
   buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

   defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion 11
       targetSdkVersion 22
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
   }

   dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
      compile project(':audioreccommons')
   }
   ```

Comment: don't add `support v4`, it's part of `appcompat v7`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - still does not work...I've sync,clean and rebuild the project after removing v4 from gradle...

Comment: did you install the support repository and support library in the SDK manager?

Comment: Yes, of course. I've also update to the last version (22.1.0)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue was caused by GooglePlayService lib which already contained the v4 support library. The solution was to exclude support-v4 when compiling playServices.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':audiorecengine')
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```

Also I removed v4 from gradle dependency because it is already contained by the v7 support lib